# How to modify the GeoServer preview page - format=application/openlayers&layers

Tags: geoserver, openlayers

I want to modify the GeoServer preview page that brings up a simple OpenLayers page.

The GeoServer documentation is very rare: [OpenLayers format=application/openlayers](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/services/wms/outputformats.html)
Just saying: 'Generates an OpenLayers HTML application.'

Where and how can I **modify this page**? For example, I want to expand the map preview.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to modify how the default OpenLayers preview page works, you'll need to modify the GeoServer codebase.

Alternately, you can create your own standalone webpage. I don't recommend copying GeoServer's generated code because last I checked it was still using OpenLayers 2 (latest is OpenLayers 4).

Comment: Nowadays it's using OpenLayers 3, but yes, it's just a preview, not meant to be used as a base for a larger application.